# Do "Special Ops" mission level ups carry over to Multplayer mode weapons and perks?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I started out playing Special Ops, and unlocked a few guns and gained rank.
I wasn't really paying attention when I dove into Multiplayer... But does anyone know if what you achieve in Special Ops transfers to Multi-player leveling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Spec Ops has its own leveling and unlock system. The leveling and unlocks in multiplayer are unrelated. In fact, I believe that there are some guns that are only in Spec Ops, and others that are only in multiplayer.